# How to sign-in to EKS cluster without aws-auth configmap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster where my `aws-auth` configmap has the aws roles to access the cluster. However, the aws roles mapped to it are all deleted. Now I cannot connect to the cluster.

I tried creating the same roles with the same name but because it was AWS SSO created role, I cannot re-use the name. AWS doesn't allow it.

Can someone please help me out of this please?

Answer (score -2):

You can find previous SSO role name from cloudtrail event logs. Once you find the exact name create the iam role with same name.